# Post a serialized ASP.NET Model and a file with single Jquery Ajax call in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a movie library application in asp.net. In admin page, I need to add a movie to the database(details such as name, actors, poster url). And also I need to upload the trailer of the movie to a specific folder in the server.

In my AddMovie View(which is strongly typed to a MovieDetails Model), I have a forms to include movie information as text and with a file input to upload a file(movie trailer). Within my controller I get the binded MovieDetails model and the uploaded file seperately as two parameters as follows.

[image: AddMovie Controller]

At first I just posted from my view to this controller without using ajax. I was able to get the Model and the file to the controller to do what I needed to do.

Then I moved to ajax and tried to do this without page refresh.

[image]

Now no files cannot be uploaded. I tried to debug and noticed that `uploadFile` parameter of the controller is null although I attached a file to the file input in the view.

Is there any way to post the model to the controller and upload the file without completely changing the controller and using a single ajax call?

Or else is it possible pass the file path through a model attribute, access that file path and upload the relevant file in the controller, using Ajax.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As Darin mentioned, there is no simple way to handle file-uploading matters via ajax for some security reasons and you can't upload files to your server easily; but good news is there are some tricks which can resolve it, for instance, you can use jquery [AjaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) in your mvc form easily with a bit little modification. Take a look at jquery-ajax-form and its samples, you will get some good idea around it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you cannot upload files using AJAX. Modern browsers that support [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) would allow you to directly make AJAX requests containing `multipart/form-data` content. Also look at the native [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files) object.

But if you need to support legacy browsers you will need some fallback mechanism such as hidden iframes or Flash movies. Plugins such as [`blueimp`](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) would detect the browser capabilities and upload the file using the best option that the browser supports.